# what is best ThreeJS loader to use for Animated models?

Tags: three.js

what is the most supported format to load on ThreeJS for Animated models by bones with multi-textures ?

i find most examples (including JSON) are showing models with single texture.

if JSON is the best, where can i find working example model with multi-textures? i tried to export one from Blender but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had also problems with multi-textured animated models last time and best solution I've found was 
http://www.cgdev.net/json/index.php

There is an exporter and a loader for threejs inside.

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks for kind reply, i work on this, but im confused how to calculate "rot" values for Bones.
can you help on this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43607039/understanding-rotq-array-for-bones-in-jsonformat-directx-to-json